# Show an image stored by ngCordova in an html img tag (Angular)

Tags: html, angularjs, file, cordova, ngcordova

I currently use ngCordova in a project, I need to store images locally that I get from a web-service

```
$http.get('webservice/image/' + item.imageId).then(function(response) {
  $cordovaFile.writeFile(
    cordova.dataDirectory,
    item.imageId,
    response.data,
    true).then(function() {
    item.imagePath = cordova.dataDirectory + item.imageId;
    item.update();
  });
});
```

it stores the image in: (I can see them in Xcode, so they are saved)

```
file:///var/mobile/Application/<appID>/Library/NoCloud/<imageId>.png
```

Then I try to show them in a view:

```
<img ng-src="{{item.imagePath}}"/>
```

And it doesn't show any images, and I tried other imagePath combination:

```
item.imagePath = ./Library/NoCloud/<imageId>.png
item.imagePath = Library/NoCloud/<imageId>.png
item.imagePath = ./<imageId>.png
item.imagePath = <imageId>.png
item.imagePath = ../../Library/NoCloud/<imageId>.png
```

Comment: have you tried removing the curly brackets? also are you sure the item object is binded to the `$scope`?

Comment: Yes and Yes :D I didn't show all the code for the sake of briefly and If I remove the curly brackets, item won't get evaluated and ng-src will take it has a string

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work this way:

```
$cordovaFileTransfer.download(
  encodeURI('webservice/image/' + item.imageId),
  cordova.file.dataDirectory + item.ImageId, {},
  true).then(function(response) {
    item.Image = response.toInternalURL();
    item.update();
}));
```